# Why gem demands new version changes if the old version of gem used?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, graphviz

I feel a little bit confused about my situation. 
These are the versions of elasticsearch gems I'm using:

```
elasticsearch (1.0.12)
      elasticsearch-api (= 1.0.12)
      elasticsearch-transport (= 1.0.12)
    elasticsearch-api (1.0.12)
      multi_json
    elasticsearch-model (0.1.7)
      activesupport (> 3)
      elasticsearch (> 0.4)
      hashie
    elasticsearch-rails (0.1.7)
elasticsearch-transport (1.0.12)
```

But the rspec tests fail and the fail message is

> The [string] type is removed in 5.0 and automatic upgrade failed because parameters [index_analyzer] are not supported for automatic upgrades.

Why does it want me to use the upgraded syntax and tells me about 5 version changes if I'm still using an older version?

I know it is possible to solve this issue by upgrading, but still, I think it's strange that my code wants to be upgraded despite using an old version gem.

Thank you in advance for any ideas!

Here is my Gemfile.lock:

```
    GIT
      specs:
        activeadmin (1.0.0.pre4)
          arbre (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
          bourbon
          coffee-rails
          formtastic (~> 3.1)
          formtastic_i18n
          inherited_resources (~> 1.6)
          jquery-rails
          jquery-ui-rails
          kaminari (~> 0.15)
          railties (>= 3.2, < 5.1)
          ransack (~> 1.3)
          sass-rails
          sprockets (< 4.1)

    GEM
      specs:
        CFPropertyList (2.3.1)
        actionmailer (4.2.7.1)
          actionpack (= 4.2.7.1)
          actionview (= 4.2.7.1)
          activejob (= 4.2.7.1)
          mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
          rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
        actionpack (4.2.7.1)
          actionview (= 4.2.7.1)
          activesupport (= 4.2.7.1)
          rack (~> 1.6)
          rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
          rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
          rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
        actionview (4.2.7.1)
          activesupport (= 4.2.7.1)
          builder (~> 3.1)
          erubis (~> 2.7.0)
          rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
          rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
        active_link_to (1.0.2)
          actionpack
        active_model_serializers (0.10.2)
          actionpack (>= 4.1, < 6)
          activemodel (>= 4.1, < 6)
          jsonapi (~> 0.1.1.beta2)
          railties (>= 4.1, < 6)
        activejob (4.2.7.1)
          activesupport (= 4.2.7.1)
          globalid (>= 0.3.0)
        activemodel (4.2.7.1)
          activesupport (= 4.2.7.1)
          builder (~> 3.1)
        activerecord (4.2.7.1)
          activemodel (= 4.2.7.1)
          activesupport (= 4.2.7.1)
          arel (~> 6.0)
        activerecord-postgres-earthdistance (0.4.2)
          pg
          rails (>= 3.1)
          rake
        activesupport (4.2.7.1)
          i18n (~> 0.7)
          json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
          minitest (~> 5.1)
          thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.4)
          tzinfo (~> 1.1)
        addressable (2.3.8)
        arbre (1.1.1)
          activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
        arel (6.0.3)
        ast (2.3.0)
        autoprefixer-rails (6.4.1)
          execjs
        awesome_print (1.6.1)
        babel-source (5.8.35)
        babel-transpiler (0.7.0)
          babel-source (>= 4.0, < 6)
          execjs (~> 2.0)
        bcrypt (3.1.10)
        binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
          debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
        bourbon (4.2.7)
          sass (~> 3.4)
          thor (~> 0.19)
        brakeman (3.4.1)
        breadcrumbs_on_rails (3.0.1)
        builder (3.2.2)
        bullet (4.14.4)
          activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
          uniform_notifier (>= 1.6.0)
        bundler-audit (0.3.1)
          bundler (~> 1.2)
          thor (~> 0.18)
        byebug (9.0.6)
        capybara (2.7.1)
          addressable
          mime-types (>= 1.16)
          nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
          rack (>= 1.0.0)
          rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
          xpath (~> 2.0)
        capybara-webkit (1.11.1)
          capybara (>= 2.3.0, < 2.8.0)
          json
        carrierwave (0.10.0)
          activemodel (>= 3.2.0)
          activesupport (>= 3.2.0)
          json (>= 1.7)
          mime-types (>= 1.16)
        choice (0.2.0)
        chronic (0.10.2)
        code_analyzer (0.4.5)
          sexp_processor
        codeclimate-test-reporter (0.4.7)
          simplecov (>= 0.7.1, < 1.0.0)
        coderay (1.1.0)
        coffee-rails (4.2.1)
          coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
          railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.2.x)
        coffee-script (2.4.1)
          coffee-script-source
          execjs
        coffee-script-source (1.11.1)
        colored (1.2)
        concurrent-ruby (1.0.2)
        connection_pool (2.2.0)
        countries (2.0.2)
          i18n_data (~> 0.7.0)
          money (~> 6.7)
          unicode_utils (~> 1.4)
        crack (0.4.2)
          safe_yaml (~> 1.0.0)
        database_cleaner (1.4.1)
        debug_inspector (0.0.2)
        decent_exposure (2.3.2)
        deep_merge (1.1.1)
        devise (3.5.6)
          bcrypt (~> 3.0)
          orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
          railties (>= 3.2.6, < 5)
          responders
          thread_safe (~> 0.1)
          warden (~> 1.2.3)
        diff-lcs (1.2.5)
        docile (1.1.5)
        domain_name (0.5.24)
          unf (>= 0.0.5, < 1.0.0)
        dotenv (2.0.0)
        dotenv-rails (2.0.0)
          dotenv (= 2.0.0)
        elasticsearch (1.0.12)
          elasticsearch-api (= 1.0.12)
          elasticsearch-transport (= 1.0.12)
        elasticsearch-api (1.0.12)
          multi_json
        elasticsearch-model (0.1.7)
          activesupport (> 3)
          elasticsearch (> 0.4)
          hashie
        elasticsearch-rails (0.1.7)
        elasticsearch-transport (1.0.12)
          faraday
          multi_json
        email_spec (1.6.0)
          launchy (~> 2.1)
          mail (~> 2.2)
        erubis (2.7.0)
        excon (0.45.3)
        execjs (2.7.0)
        factory_girl (4.5.0)
          activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
        factory_girl_rails (4.5.0)
          factory_girl (~> 4.5.0)
          railties (>= 3.0.0)
        faker (1.6.6)
          i18n (~> 0.5)
        faraday (0.9.1)
          multipart-post (>= 1.2, < 3)
        fast_stack (0.1.0)
          rake
          rake-compiler
        fission (0.5.0)
          CFPropertyList (~> 2.2)
        flag-icons-rails (1.1.2)
          sass (~> 3.2)
        flamegraph (0.1.0)
          fast_stack
        fog (1.29.0)
          fog-atmos
          fog-aws (~> 0.0)
          fog-brightbox (~> 0.4)
          fog-core (~> 1.27, >= 1.27.4)
          fog-ecloud
          fog-json
          fog-local
          fog-powerdns (>= 0.1.1)
          fog-profitbricks
          fog-radosgw (>= 0.0.2)
          fog-riakcs
          fog-sakuracloud (>= 0.0.4)
          fog-serverlove
          fog-softlayer
          fog-storm_on_demand
          fog-terremark
          fog-vmfusion
          fog-voxel
          fog-xml (~> 0.1.1)
          ipaddress (~> 0.5)
          nokogiri (~> 1.5, >= 1.5.11)
        fog-atmos (0.1.0)
          fog-core
          fog-xml
        fog-aws (0.1.2)
          fog-core (~> 1.27)
          fog-json (~> 1.0)
          fog-xml (~> 0.1)
          ipaddress (~> 0.8)
        fog-brightbox (0.7.1)
          fog-core (~> 1.22)
          fog-json
          inflecto (~> 0.0.2)
        fog-core (1.30.0)
          builder
          excon (~> 0.45)
          formatador (~> 0.2)
          mime-types
          net-scp (~> 1.1)
          net-ssh (>= 2.1.3)
        fog-ecloud (0.1.1)
          fog-core
          fog-xml
        fog-json (1.0.1)
          fog-core (~> 1.0)
          multi_json (~> 1.0)
        fog-local (0.2.1)
          fog-core (~> 1.27)
        fog-powerdns (0.1.1)
          fog-core (~> 1.27)
          fog-json (~> 1.0)
          fog-xml (~> 0.1)
        fog-profitbricks (0.0.2)
          fog-core
          fog-xml
          nokogiri
        fog-radosgw (0.0.4)
          fog-core (>= 1.21.0)
          fog-json
          fog-xml (>= 0.0.1)
        fog-riakcs (0.1.0)
          fog-core
          fog-json
          fog-xml
        fog-sakuracloud (1.0.1)
          fog-core
          fog-json
        fog-serverlove (0.1.2)
          fog-core
          fog-json
        fog-softlayer (0.4.5)
          fog-core
          fog-json
        fog-storm_on_demand (0.1.1)
          fog-core
          fog-json
        fog-terremark (0.1.0)
          fog-core
          fog-xml
        fog-vmfusion (0.1.0)
          fission
          fog-core
        fog-voxel (0.1.0)
          fog-core
          fog-xml
        fog-xml (0.1.2)
          fog-core
          nokogiri (~> 1.5, >= 1.5.11)
        foreman (0.82.0)
          thor (~> 0.19.1)
        formatador (0.2.5)
        formtastic (3.1.4)
          actionpack (>= 3.2.13)
        formtastic_i18n (0.6.0)
        formulaic (0.2.0)
          activesupport
          capybara
          i18n
        foundation-icons-sass-rails (3.0.0)
          railties (>= 3.1.1)
          sass-rails (>= 3.1.1)
        foundation-rails (5.5.1.1)
          railties (>= 3.1.0)
          sass (>= 3.3.0, < 3.5)
        friendly_id (5.1.0)
          activerecord (>= 4.0.0)
        fuubar (2.0.0)
          rspec (~> 3.0)
          ruby-progressbar (~> 1.4)
        globalid (0.3.7)
          activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
        has_scope (0.6.0)
          actionpack (>= 3.2, < 5)
          activesupport (>= 3.2, < 5)
        hashie (3.4.1)
        heroku (3.32.0)
          heroku-api (>= 0.3.19)
          launchy (>= 0.3.2)
          multi_json (>= 1.10)
          netrc (>= 0.10.0)
          rest-client (>= 1.6.0)
          rubyzip (>= 0.9.9)
        heroku-api (0.3.23)
          excon (~> 0.44)
          multi_json (~> 1.8)
        http-cookie (1.0.2)
          domain_name (~> 0.5)
        i18n (0.7.0)
        i18n_data (0.7.0)
        inflecto (0.0.2)
        inherited_resources (1.6.0)
          actionpack (>= 3.2, < 5)
          has_scope (~> 0.6.0.rc)
          railties (>= 3.2, < 5)
          responders
        inline_svg (0.11.0)
          activesupport (>= 4.0)
          loofah (>= 2.0)
          nokogiri (~> 1.6)
        interactor (3.1.0)
        ipaddress (0.8.0)
        jquery-rails (4.0.4)
          rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0)
          railties (>= 4.2.0)
          thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
        jquery-ui-rails (5.0.5)
          railties (>= 3.2.16)
        json (1.8.3)
        jsonapi (0.1.1.beta2)
          json (~> 1.8)
        jwt (1.5.0)
        kaminari (0.17.0)
          actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
          activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
        launchy (2.4.3)
          addressable (~> 2.3)
        letter_opener (1.3.0)
          launchy (~> 2.2)
        libv8 (3.16.14.15)
        loofah (2.0.3)
          nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
        mail (2.6.4)
          mime-types (>= 1.16, < 4)
        masonry-rails (0.2.4)
          railties
        memory_profiler (0.9.4)
        metamagic (3.1.7)
          rails (>= 3.0.0)
        method_source (0.8.2)
        mime-types (2.99.3)
        mini_magick (4.2.4)
        mini_portile2 (2.1.0)
        minitest (5.10.1)
        money (6.7.1)
          i18n (>= 0.6.4, <= 0.7.0)
          sixarm_ruby_unaccent (>= 1.1.1, < 2)
        multi_json (1.12.1)
        multi_xml (0.5.5)
        multipart-post (2.0.0)
        mysql (2.9.1)
        net-scp (1.2.1)
          net-ssh (>= 2.6.5)
        net-ssh (2.9.2)
        netrc (0.10.3)
        newrelic_rpm (3.12.1.298)
        nokogiri (1.6.8.1)
          mini_portile2 (~> 2.1.0)
        oauth2 (1.0.0)
          faraday (>= 0.8, < 0.10)
          jwt (~> 1.0)
          multi_json (~> 1.3)
          multi_xml (~> 0.5)
          rack (~> 1.2)
        oj (2.18.0)
        omniauth (1.2.2)
          hashie (>= 1.2, < 4)
          rack (~> 1.0)
        omniauth-facebook (2.0.1)
          omniauth-oauth2 (~> 1.2)
        omniauth-google-oauth2 (0.2.4)
          omniauth (~> 1.0)
          omniauth-oauth2 (~> 1.1)
        omniauth-oauth2 (1.3.0)
          oauth2 (~> 1.0)
          omniauth (~> 1.2)
        orm_adapter (0.5.0)
        parser (2.3.3.1)
          ast (~> 2.2)
        pg (0.18.1)
        pgbackups-archive (1.0.3)
          fog-aws
          heroku (>= 3.28.6, <= 3.32)
          rake
        polyamorous (1.3.1)
          activerecord (>= 3.0)
        powerpack (0.1.1)
        pry (0.10.1)
          coderay (~> 1.1.0)
          method_source (~> 0.8.1)
          slop (~> 3.4)
        pry-rails (0.3.4)
          pry (>= 0.9.10)
        puma (3.6.2)
        pundit (1.1.0)
          activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
        quiet_assets (1.1.0)
          railties (>= 3.1, < 5.0)
        rabl (0.13.1)
          activesupport (>= 2.3.14)
        rack (1.6.5)
        rack-canonical-host (0.1.0)
          addressable
          rack (~> 1.0)
        rack-cors (0.4.0)
        rack-mini-profiler (0.10.1)
          rack (>= 1.2.0)
        rack-test (0.6.3)
          rack (>= 1.0)
        rails (4.2.7.1)
          actionmailer (= 4.2.7.1)
          actionpack (= 4.2.7.1)
          actionview (= 4.2.7.1)
          activejob (= 4.2.7.1)
          activemodel (= 4.2.7.1)
          activerecord (= 4.2.7.1)
          activesupport (= 4.2.7.1)
          bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
          railties (= 4.2.7.1)
          sprockets-rails
        rails-assets-autosize (3.0.17)
        rails-assets-dropzone (4.3.0)
        rails-assets-jquery (2.1.4)
        rails-assets-jquery-bar-rating (1.1.0)
          rails-assets-jquery (>= 1.7.2)
        rails-assets-jquery-cascading-dropdown (1.2.5)
        rails-assets-jquery-placeholder (2.1.1)
          rails-assets-jquery (>= 1.6)
        rails-assets-jquery-ui (1.11.4)
          rails-assets-jquery (>= 1.6)
        rails-assets-lite-uploader (2.2.0)
          rails-assets-jquery (>= 1.8)
        rails-assets-lodash (4.14.2)
        rails-assets-microplugin (0.0.3)
        rails-assets-pnotify (3.0.0)
          rails-assets-jquery (>= 1.6)
        rails-assets-rangeslider.js (1.2.1)
          rails-assets-jquery (>= 1.9.0)
        rails-assets-sachinchoolur--lightGallery (1.3.5)
          rails-assets-jquery (>= 1.7.0)
        rails-assets-selectize (0.12.3)
          rails-assets-jquery (>= 1.7.0)
          rails-assets-microplugin (~> 0.0.0)
          rails-assets-sifter (~> 0.5.0)
        rails-assets-sifter (0.5.2)
        rails-assets-timepicker (1.7.0)
          rails-assets-jquery (>= 1.7)
        rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
          activesupport (>= 4.2.0.alpha)
        rails-dom-testing (1.0.7)
          activesupport (>= 4.2.0.beta, < 5.0)
          nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
          rails-deprecated_sanitizer (>= 1.0.1)
        rails-erd (1.4.0)
          activerecord (>= 3.2)
          activesupport (>= 3.2)
          choice (~> 0.2.0)
          ruby-graphviz (~> 1.2)
        rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
          loofah (~> 2.0)
        rails_12factor (0.0.3)
          rails_serve_static_assets
          rails_stdout_logging
        rails_best_practices (1.15.7)
          activesupport
          code_analyzer (>= 0.4.3)
          colored
          erubis
          i18n
          json
          require_all
          ruby-progressbar
        rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.4)
        rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
        railties (4.2.7.1)
          actionpack (= 4.2.7.1)
          activesupport (= 4.2.7.1)
          rake (>= 0.8.7)
          thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
        rainbow (2.1.0)
        rake (12.0.0)
        rake-compiler (0.9.5)
          rake
        ransack (1.8.2)
          actionpack (>= 3.0)
          activerecord (>= 3.0)
          activesupport (>= 3.0)
          i18n
          polyamorous (~> 1.3)
        react-rails (1.8.1)
          babel-transpiler (>= 0.7.0)
          coffee-script-source (~> 1.8)
          connection_pool
          execjs
          railties (>= 3.2)
          tilt
        ref (2.0.0)
        remotipart (1.2.1)
        require_all (1.3.2)
        responders (2.3.0)
          railties (>= 4.2.0, < 5.1)
        rest-client (1.8.0)
          http-cookie (>= 1.0.2, < 2.0)
          mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3.0)
          netrc (~> 0.7)
        rinku (1.7.3)
        rollbar (2.13.3)
          multi_json
        rspec (3.5.0)
          rspec-core (~> 3.5.0)
          rspec-expectations (~> 3.5.0)
          rspec-mocks (~> 3.5.0)
        rspec-core (3.5.4)
          rspec-support (~> 3.5.0)
        rspec-expectations (3.5.0)
          diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
          rspec-support (~> 3.5.0)
        rspec-mocks (3.5.0)
          diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
          rspec-support (~> 3.5.0)
        rspec-rails (3.5.2)
          actionpack (>= 3.0)
          activesupport (>= 3.0)
          railties (>= 3.0)
          rspec-core (~> 3.5.0)
          rspec-expectations (~> 3.5.0)
          rspec-mocks (~> 3.5.0)
          rspec-support (~> 3.5.0)
        rspec-support (3.5.0)
        rubocop (0.46.0)
          parser (>= 2.3.1.1, < 3.0)
          powerpack (~> 0.1)
          rainbow (>= 1.99.1, < 3.0)
          ruby-progressbar (~> 1.7)
          unicode-display_width (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
        ruby-graphviz (1.2.2)
        ruby-progressbar (1.8.1)
        rubyzip (1.1.7)
        safe_yaml (1.0.4)
        sass (3.4.22)
        sass-rails (5.0.6)
          railties (>= 4.0.0, < 6)
          sass (~> 3.1)
          sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
          sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
          tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
        scss_lint (0.38.0)
          rainbow (~> 2.0)
          sass (~> 3.4.1)
        seedbank (0.3.0)
        sexp_processor (4.7.0)
        shoulda-matchers (2.8.0)
          activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
        simple_form (3.1.0)
          actionpack (~> 4.0)
          activemodel (~> 4.0)
        simplecov (0.9.2)
          docile (~> 1.1.0)
          multi_json (~> 1.0)
          simplecov-html (~> 0.9.0)
        simplecov-html (0.9.0)
        sitemap_generator (5.2.0)
          builder (~> 3.0)
        sixarm_ruby_unaccent (1.1.1)
        skim (0.10.0)
          coffee-script
          coffee-script-source (>= 1.2.0)
          slim (>= 3.0)
          sprockets (>= 2, < 4)
        slim (3.0.3)
          temple (~> 0.7.3)
          tilt (>= 1.3.3, < 2.1)
        slim-rails (3.0.1)
          actionmailer (>= 3.1, < 5.0)
          actionpack (>= 3.1, < 5.0)
          activesupport (>= 3.1, < 5.0)
          railties (>= 3.1, < 5.0)
          slim (~> 3.0)
        slop (3.6.0)
        sprockets (3.7.0)
          concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
          rack (> 1, < 3)
        sprockets-rails (3.2.0)
          actionpack (>= 4.0)
          activesupport (>= 4.0)
          sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
        stackprof (0.2.7)
        temple (0.7.5)
        test_after_commit (0.4.1)
          activerecord (>= 3.2)
        therubyracer (0.12.2)
          libv8 (~> 3.16.14.0)
          ref
        thor (0.19.4)
        thread_safe (0.3.5)
        tilt (2.0.5)
        truncate_html (0.9.3)
        tzinfo (1.2.2)
          thread_safe (~> 0.1)
        uglifier (2.7.2)
          execjs (>= 0.3.0)
          json (>= 1.8.0)
        unf (0.1.4)
          unf_ext
        unf_ext (0.0.7.1)
        unicode-display_width (1.1.1)
        unicode_utils (1.4.0)
        uniform_notifier (1.8.0)
        validate_url (1.0.0)
          activemodel (>= 3.0.0)
          addressable
        warden (1.2.6)
          rack (>= 1.0)
        web-console (2.1.3)
          activemodel (>= 4.0)
          binding_of_caller (>= 0.7.2)
          railties (>= 4.0)
          sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
        webmock (1.21.0)
          addressable (>= 2.3.6)
          crack (>= 0.3.2)
        xpath (2.0.0)
          nokogiri (~> 1.3)

    PLATFORMS
      ruby

    DEPENDENCIES
      active_link_to
      active_model_serializers
      activeadmin!
      activerecord-postgres-earthdistance
      addressable
      autoprefixer-rails
      awesome_print
      brakeman
      breadcrumbs_on_rails
      bullet
      bundler-audit
      byebug
      capybara
      capybara-webkit
      carrierwave
      chronic
      codeclimate-test-reporter
      coffee-rails
      countries
      database_cleaner
      decent_exposure
      deep_merge
      devise
      dotenv-rails
      elasticsearch-model
      elasticsearch-rails
      email_spec
      factory_girl_rails
      faker
      flag-icons-rails
      flamegraph
      fog
      fog-aws
      foreman
      formulaic
      foundation-icons-sass-rails
      foundation-rails
      friendly_id
      fuubar
      inline_svg
      interactor
      jquery-rails (= 4.0.4)
      jquery-ui-rails (= 5.0.5)
      kaminari
      launchy
      letter_opener
      masonry-rails
      memory_profiler
      metamagic
      mini_magick
      mysql
      newrelic_rpm
      oj
      omniauth
      omniauth-facebook
      omniauth-google-oauth2
      pg
      pgbackups-archive
      pry-rails
      puma
      pundit
      quiet_assets
      rabl
      rack-canonical-host
      rack-cors
      rack-mini-profiler
      rails (= 4.2.7.1)
      rails-assets-autosize!
      rails-assets-dropzone!
      rails-assets-jquery-bar-rating!
      rails-assets-jquery-cascading-dropdown!
      rails-assets-jquery-placeholder!
      rails-assets-jquery-ui!
      rails-assets-lite-uploader!
      rails-assets-lodash!
      rails-assets-pnotify!
      rails-assets-rangeslider.js!
      rails-assets-sachinchoolur--lightGallery!
      rails-assets-selectize!
      rails-assets-timepicker!
      rails-erd
      rails_12factor
      rails_best_practices
      react-rails
      remotipart
      responders
      rinku
      rollbar
      rspec-rails
      rubocop
      sass-rails
      scss_lint
      seedbank
      shoulda-matchers
      simple_form
      sitemap_generator
      skim
      slim
      slim-rails
      stackprof
      test_after_commit
      therubyracer
      truncate_html
      uglifier
      validate_url
      web-console
      webmock

    RUBY VERSION
       ruby 2.3.1p112

    BUNDLED WITH
       1.13.6
```

and Gemfile:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

ruby "2.3.1"

gem "pg"
gem "rails", "4.2.7.1"

gem "flamegraph"
gem "memory_profiler"
gem "rack-mini-profiler"
gem "stackprof"

# frontend stack: preprocessors, libraries, minifiers, assets
# plus view stack: helpers, builders, etc.
gem "active_link_to"
gem "autoprefixer-rails"
gem "coffee-rails"
gem "flag-icons-rails"
gem "foundation-icons-sass-rails"
gem "foundation-rails"
gem "inline_svg"
gem "jquery-rails", "4.0.4"
gem "jquery-ui-rails", "5.0.5"
gem "masonry-rails"
gem "metamagic"
gem "react-rails"
gem "remotipart"
gem "rinku"
gem "sass-rails"
gem "simple_form"
gem "skim"
gem "slim"
gem "therubyracer", platforms: :ruby
gem "truncate_html"
gem "uglifier"

source "https://rails-assets.org" do
  gem "rails-assets-autosize"
  gem "rails-assets-dropzone"
  gem "rails-assets-jquery-bar-rating"
  gem "rails-assets-jquery-cascading-dropdown"
  gem "rails-assets-jquery-placeholder"
  gem "rails-assets-jquery-ui"
  gem "rails-assets-lite-uploader"
  gem "rails-assets-lodash"
  gem "rails-assets-pnotify"
  gem "rails-assets-rangeslider.js"
  gem "rails-assets-sachinchoolur--lightGallery"
  gem "rails-assets-selectize"
  gem "rails-assets-timepicker"
end

# all other gems
gem "active_model_serializers"
gem "activeadmin", git: "https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin"
gem "addressable"
gem "breadcrumbs_on_rails"
gem "countries"
gem "decent_exposure"
gem "deep_merge", require: "deep_merge/rails_compat"
gem "devise"
gem "elasticsearch-model"
gem "elasticsearch-rails"
gem "friendly_id"
gem "interactor"
gem "kaminari"
gem "newrelic_rpm"
gem "oj"
gem "puma"
gem "rabl"
gem "rack-canonical-host"
gem "rack-cors"
gem "responders"
gem "rollbar"
gem "seedbank"
gem "validate_url"

# services
gem "activerecord-postgres-earthdistance"
gem "carrierwave"
gem "fog"
gem "fog-aws"
gem "mini_magick"
gem "pundit"
gem "sitemap_generator"

gem "omniauth"
gem "omniauth-facebook"
gem "omniauth-google-oauth2"

gem "pgbackups-archive"

group :data_migration do
  gem "chronic"
  gem "mysql"
end

group :staging, :production do
  gem "rails_12factor"
end

group :test do
  gem "capybara"
  gem "capybara-webkit"
  gem "codeclimate-test-reporter", require: false
  gem "database_cleaner"
  gem "email_spec"
  gem "formulaic"
  gem "launchy"
  gem "shoulda-matchers"
  gem "test_after_commit"
  gem "webmock", require: false
end

group :development, :test, :staging do
  gem "factory_girl_rails"
  gem "faker"
end

group :development, :test do
  gem "awesome_print"
  gem "brakeman", require: false
  gem "bundler-audit"
  gem "byebug"
  gem "dotenv-rails"
  gem "fuubar"
  gem "pry-rails"
  gem "rails_best_practices"
  gem "rspec-rails"
  gem "rubocop"
  gem "scss_lint", require: false
end

group :development do
  gem "bullet"
  gem "foreman"
  gem "letter_opener"
  gem "quiet_assets"
  gem "rails-erd"
  gem "slim-rails"
  gem "web-console"
end
```

Comment: please post full stack trace and use code editor here with indentation or highlight your code and click on the`{}` icon in the editor and it will code indent it.

Comment: just throwing out a guess here, perhaps you have a newer elasticsearch version that is incompatile with the older gem. The gem isn't the only piece of the puzzle here, there's also the elasticsearch server. Perhaps add your elasticsearch versionn to the question

Comment: please add your `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` files code here.

Comment: @SachinSingh done

Comment: try specifying gem version in `Gemfile` for `elasticsearch-rails` gem and run `bundle install` command

Comment: @SachinSingh it is said here https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails  that I can specify the version by adding gem 'elasticsearch-rails', github: 'elastic/elasticsearch-rails', branch: '1.x', however bundler says there is no such gem version. If I don't specify any of the versions, it installs 1.0.12.

Comment: @maxpleaner mac uses elasticsearch 6.2.3, can that be a problem? Our tests fail on semaphoreci also

Comment: Branch "1.x" doesn't exist in the `elasticsearch-rails` repo. The oldest one I can see is "2.x".

Please get in touch on Semaphore support, if you need help with running your tests.